# Why am I getting the TypeError: calcFolders() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'?

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror

I'm stuck trying to figure this out. I have looked at other stackoverflow threads on this, and still can't seem to resolve it. Why does my code not work the first time I run it, when I open PyCharm, but it does work the second time?

The first time I always get the error "**TypeError: calcFolders() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**"

This program is a simple Tkinter app that allows me to generate a range folders named with any prefix, with an incremental suffix. FOLDER_1, FOLDER_2, FOLDER_3 etc.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import folderNames
import createDirs

root = Tk()
root.title("Create Folders")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

directory = StringVar()
adirectory = StringVar()
prefix = StringVar()
startN = IntVar()
endN = IntVar()
useDir = StringVar()
def calcFolders(self):
    try:
        if len(adir_entry.get())==0:
            useDir = dir_entry.get()
        else:
            useDir = "C:\\Data\\92175\\My Documents\\ARTS\\ACTION\\"+adir_entry.get()+"\\"
        a = folderNames.getf(start_entry.get(), end_entry.get(), pref_entry.get())
        createDirs.createD(useDir,a)
    except ValueError:
        pass

dir_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=14, textvariable = directory)
dir_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

adir_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=14, textvariable = adirectory)
adir_entry.grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

pref_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=14, textvariable = prefix)
pref_entry.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky=(W, E))

start_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=14, textvariable = startN)
start_entry.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W, E))

end_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=14, textvariable = endN)
end_entry.grid(column=4, row=4, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Directory").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="or: ARTS # such as \"A0380\"").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Prefix").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Start").grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="End").grid(column=3, row=4, sticky=E)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="CREATE", command=calcFolders).grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=N)



for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

dir_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', calcFolders)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: None of your code is an actual class so having a function that has `self` in it doesn't make since here. I suspect you copied that method out of a class and are trying to use it in a non OOP way. So to do this remove `self` and you should be fine. As it stands now `self` is being treated as a required positional argument so you must pass something to the function.

Answer (score 2):

`calcFolders` isn't an instance method of some class, you don't need the usual `self` argument that refers to the instance of that class. For more about self, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python). Just change your definition to:

```
def calcFolders():
    try:
        if len(adir_entry.get())==0:
            useDir = dir_entry.get()
        else:
            useDir = "C:\\Data\\92175\\My Documents\\ARTS\\ACTION\\"+adir_entry.get()+"\\"
        a = folderNames.getf(start_entry.get(), end_entry.get(), pref_entry.get())
        createDirs.createD(useDir,a)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

You should take a look at what arguments get sent to the `command` callback when your button is clicked. It looks like [tkinter](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) doesn't expect the callback to accept any arguments though.